# Pular campo input após click(function() {

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Alguem sabe como pular para o próximo campo (input) utilizando a função dentro do evento:

```
click(function() {
```

Não pode ser por ID pois estou utilizando dentro de uma div que utiliza a função CLONE do jquery. Grato

Comment: Você pode elaborar mais sua pergunta? Grato!

Comment: Olá @NotTheRealHemingway estou precisando pular para o proximo campo input após o usuário selecionar a função em ajax que será feita no  click(function() {

Answer (score 0):

Consegui. Utilizei a função .focus(); e funcionou... Valeuu!

Comment: Na verdade o `onfocus` não pula para o próximo campo, esse evento dispara quando o campo em questão recebe `focus`, para pular para um determinado campo você direciona o `focus`, para o campo que deseja através da função `focus()`... Ao meu ver são coisas diferentes..

Comment: Exatamente, coloquei o focus() no proximo campo e consegui.